# Hello? Who is there?

Tags: riddle

Down is to the floor
Up is to expect more
Out is to suspend
Off is to pretend
Over is upside down
On is something brown

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Knock

Down is to the floor

> Knock down = to strike to the ground

Up is to expect more

> Knock up = to make a woman pregnant (expecting a child).

Out is to suspend

> Knock out = to stop something working.

Off is to pretend

> Knock-off = a copy or imitation, especially of an expensive product.

Over is upside down

> Knock over = to turn upside-down.

On is something brown

> [Knock on **wood**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocking_on_wood)

Title

> Refers to knocking on a door or perhaps a [Knock-knock joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knock-knock_joke)

Comment: perfect answer!