# A Riddle of Opportunity

Tags: riddle, word

Inspired by a previous question [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91572/hello-who-is-there/91573)

> Up is a surprise,
>   Down is to deny.
>   Under folds down,
>   Over, a small pie,
>   In begins at night,
>   Out is who attends,
>   On tends to excite,
>   Off comes with a bend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is:

> Turn.

Up is a surprise:

> Turn up means to find something you lost, "it will turn up".

Down is to deny

> turn down is to deny a request.

Under folds down

> Turn under is to fold something downwards.

Over, a small pie

> A turnover is a small pie.

In begins at night

> Turn in means to go to bed

Out is who attends

> Turn out is who shows up (like to a party or show)

On tends to excite

> Turn on is sexy time.

Off comes with a bend

> A Turn off is like turning on a road? Like a bend?

Comment: I sure haven't missed the feeling of getting ninja'd! You're missing two lines: "Over" is (rot13) gheabire, nf va nccyr gheabire, "Off" is (rot13) gheavat bss gur serrjnl.

Comment: There's a little more to the first one: rot13(jura fbzrguvat vf n 'ghea-hc' (nf va 'n ghea-hc sbe gur obbxf') vg vf n fhecevfvat be harkcrpgrq rirag (zber guna whfg svaqvat fbzrguvat).) Quick fingers!

Comment: I think the only thing I'm missing here is how the title applies. Maybe rot13("vg vf zl ghea, zl punapr, zl bccbeghavgl" be fbzrguvat yvxr gung.)